# How to get this string concatenation correctly outputed?

Tags: c#, string

How do i get this

```
Console.WriteLine("Koordinaattipiste " + (4,2) + " on kvandrantissa 1.");
```

to print

```
(4,2)
```

instead of

```
(4, 2)
```

with the space in between?

Comment: `+ "(4,2)" +`??

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you unintentionally used a Tuple by enclosing the two values in brackets:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Koordinaattipiste ({x},{y}) on kvandrantissa 1.");
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
var t = (4, 2);
Console.WriteLine($"Koordinaattipiste ({t.Item1},{t.Item2}) on kvandrantissa 1.");
```